# Login is required to proceed

Tags: php, html

I am trying to add some content to my project website. Currently, on the contact page; users are able to submit a contact form regardless of whether they are logged in or not.

I am trying to overcome this by making the form 'submit button' do nothing and display "Login to contact us", if a user is not logged in. Sadly, i have little to no clue on how to tackle this issue. I would appreciate it if anyone can take a look at my code; and perhaps direct me in the right direction.

HTML code:

```
<section class="main-container">
<div class="main-wrapper">
<h2>Contact Us</h2>
<form class="signup-form" action="includes/contact.inc.php" method="POST">       
    <input type="text"  name="user_fullname"    required placeholder="Name">
    <input type="email" name="user_email"   required placeholder="E-mail">
    <input type="text"  name="subject" required placeholder="Subject">
    <input type="text"  name="message" style="height:250px;" required placeholder="Message">
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
</section>
```

Curent PHP code:

```
<section class="main-container">
<div class="main-wrapper">
    <?php
        if (empty($_SESSION['u_id'])) {
            echo "You are logged out!";

            if (isset ($_POST[$submit])) {


            echo "Login to contanct us!";

        } 
        } 
    ?>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Just add some ifs to the submit button. One to change the text and one to add a disabled state. You have a bigger UX problem though, what if I fill out the form before I notice I can't submit? To get this working properly UX wise you'd have to let me log in using javascript/ajax and then dynamically re enable the form submit button. Also if I have to log in either way you probably already have my name and email, so I shouldn't have to write that in again

Comment: why is this tagged as "mysql" ? there is none.

Comment: you appear to be using sessions, but not enough code to support the post.

Comment: `if (isset ($_POST[$submit]))` failed you here. I'm voting this as a typo.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php session_start(); 
$submit=$_REQUEST['submit'];
 if (empty($_SESSION['u_id'])) {
            echo "You are logged out!";                
    } 

 if (isset ($_POST[$submit])) {   
            echo "Login to contanct us!";
    } ?>
```

Comment: Thank you all for the quick reply... I mannaged to sort it out :D

Comment: Why did you add something to be read from `$_REQUEST`? That looks really strange, and I don't think it is needed for that stuff to work